# RGBA not working with HTML emails

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to send a HTML email with CSS styling.

I have the code `style = 'background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)'`
and it will not apply it, but rather makes the background completely opaque.

Comment: You could try using a transparent .png file... but I don't know if it would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the support of the mail client you're testing with, but given that RGBA values are a CSS3 feature, I wouldn't bet on much support at all. I'd suggest restricting yourself to RGB, HEX or named colors, and even then depending on the place you are using it, some clients won't support the color attribute at all.

Comment: Are there any other ways of making only the background opaque?

Comment: Not consistently. Clients like Gmail and Outlook will strip out most colors and background images.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use RGBA. You should use the full 6 digit HEX code for email eg: #FFFFFF. 3-digit HEX, doesn't work consistently, neither does RGB or color names.

Only way to layer transparency is by .PNG.

Keep in mind .PNG's don't open in older versions of Lotus Notes, but this is only a tiny percentage of users in most subscriber lists.

Comment: I even had problems in Outlook when Hex values weren't uppercase. That was quite a while ago but since then i always go the full way and make them uppercase just to be sure.